# Bootstrap 5 tooltip || popover

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, bootstrap-5

I have a little problem with use tooltip or popover in vue app from bootstrap.

```
<template>
...
    <i :title="person.jobTitle" class="fa fa-tag" data-bs-placement="left" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" @click="showDetails"></i>
...
</template>
```

method:

```
<script>
import {Popover} from "bootstrap";
...

methods: {
   showDetails(event) {
      new Popover(event.target)
   }
}
...
</script>
```

Im 100% sure im doing something wrong :).
I have to click twice to showup popover, and it's not closing.

While I create example:

```
    <button id="tolek" ref="tolek" title="aha" class="btn btn-secondary">
      Popover
    </button>
```

and in mounted:

```
new Popover(this.$refs.tolek)
```

it's all work beautiful.

Edit:
looks like create directive do the job:

```
<i title="Job Title" class="fa fa-tag" v-popover:click="person.jobTitle"></i>
```

directive:

```
  directives: {
    popover: {
      beforeMount(el, binding) {
        new Popover(el, {content: binding.value})
      }
    }
  },
```

Comment: Please accept the answer so others know the question is solved

Answer (score 0):

Don't mix the BS `data-bs-` attributes with Vue. Make sure to use the show() method after the popover is instantiated...

```
    methods: {
       showDetails(event) {
          this.bsPopover = new Popover(event.target, {placement: 'left', trigger: 'click'})
          this.bsPopover.show()
       }
    }
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/KhTJBYIC1u)

Answer (score 0):

**For Vue3 and Bootstrap 5 you could use Directives**

---

My answer is inspired on the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72579254/13142230) from [Sergio Azócar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15410489/sergio-az%C3%B3car) and I used TypeScript instead of JavaScript.

**Create file bootstrap.ts**

```
import { Tooltip, Popover } from 'bootstrap'

export const tooltip = {
  mounted(el: HTMLElement) {
    const tooltip = new Tooltip(el)
  }
}

export const popover = {
  mounted(el: HTMLElement) {
    const popover = new Popover(el)
  }
}
```

**In main.ts add**

```
import { tooltip } from 'your_path/tooltip'

app
 .directive('tooltip', tooltip)
 .directive('popover', popover)
 .mount("#app");
```

**And use it**

```
<button v-tooltip title="Hello world from a button!">
    I am a button
</button>

<div v-popover title="Hello world from a div!" data-bs-content="And with some amazing content">
  I am a div
</div>
```