# Adding Bootstrap 5 tooltip to Vue 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vue.js

main.js

```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js";
```

Component.vue

```
<template> 
                  <i
                class="fas fa-info-circle"
                data-bs-toggle="tooltip"
                data-bs-placement="top"
                title="Tooltip on top"
                ref="info"
              ></i>


</template>
<script>
import { Tooltip } from "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.esm.min.js";

export default {
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.$refs.info);
    new Tooltip(this.$refs.info)
  },
}
</script>
```

I tried clicking on the icon but nothing is coming out. Am I doing this wrongly?

Answer (score 16):

I've had the same problem. This code works for me.

```
import { Tooltip } from 'bootstrap'

export default {
  mounted() {
    new Tooltip(document.body, {
      selector: "[data-bs-toggle='tooltip']",
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: this thread works for me, thx a lot :)

Answer (score 8):

Here is a more elegant and modern solution that uses Typescript with the new Vue 3 script setup.

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, onMounted } from "vue";
import { Tooltip } from "bootstrap";

const info = ref(null);
let infoTooltip: Tooltip | undefined;

onMounted(() => {
  infoTooltip = new Tooltip(info.value!);
});
</script>

<template> 
  <i
    class="fas fa-info-circle"
    data-bs-toggle="tooltip"
    data-bs-placement="top"
    title="Tooltip on top"
    ref="info"
  ></i>
</template>
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as the Tooltip is tied to the element.

Answer (score 5):

You can create a directive "v-tooltip" and used in any element html.

**create file tooltip.js**

```
import { Tooltip } from 'bootstrap'

export const tooltip = {
    
  mounted(el) {
    const tooltip = new Tooltip(el)
  }

}
```

**In main.js add**

```
import { tooltip } from 'your_path/tooltip'

app.directive('tooltip', tooltip)
```

**and use it:**

```
<button v-tooltip title="Hello world!">
    I am a button
</button>
```

Comment: I'm not an expert in frontend, been struggling for hours now. This solution is so simple even I can follow. Thank you, it works.

Answer (score 3):

Simply use `import { Tooltip } from "bootstrap";`, and it should work.

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/U7pe8f3mHs)

Comment: For me, this worked.  Adding `data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" title="My tooltip."` to the container was all that was needed (no js).  One interesting thing on Mac is that `data-bs-placement="top"` doesn't place the tooltip on top.  Need to figure that out.

Answer (score 1):

I just added this code from Kyanoush at the App.Vue and it works great:

```
import { Tooltip } from 'bootstrap'

export default {
  mounted() {
    new Tooltip(document.body, {
      selector: "[data-bs-toggle='tooltip']",
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap CDN then you can also do it in **App.vue** mounted function like this :

```
<script>

export default {
  mounted() {
    var tooltipTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]'))
    var tooltipList = tooltipTriggerList.map(function (tooltipTriggerEl) {
      return new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl)
    });
  }
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For usage in one component context only

```
<script setup>
  import {Tooltip} from "bootstrap"

  const vCustomTooltip = {
    mounted: (el) => new Tooltip(el)
  }
</script>
<template>
   <div class="wrapper">
     <div v-custom-tooltip title="Email verification"></div>
     <div v-custom-tooltip title="Phone verification"></div>
   </div>
</template>
```

- Tooltip directive (vCustomTooltip) can be named whatever
- Default settings for bootstrap tooltip is used (placement top, title as tooltip value)

Answer (score 0):

for those who use cdn or direct link to bootstrap file use this code

```js
export const tooltip = {

    mounted(el) {
        const tooltip = new bootstrap.Tooltip(el)
    }

}
```