# Why is tooltip breaking collapse functionality in Vue 3 and Bootstrap 5?

Tags: vuejs3, bootstrap-5

I am trying to use tooltip in my Vue 3 + Boostrap 5 project. However, the moment I implement tooltip, collapse functionality stops working.

I have created a sample page in Stackblitz - https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-rhm9hw?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FHelloWorld.vue

I am not sure if it is a Vue 3 issue or something I am doing wrong.

I have tried following [Adding Bootstrap 5 tooltip to Vue 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69053972/adding-bootstrap-5-tooltip-to-vue-3) but it hasn't worked for me.

My project is in typescript and thought that trying it in JS might resolve it but I have discovered the same issue in JS too.

Comment: Can you explain what is not working? In your stackblitz, I see the tooltip when hovering over the "Custom Tooltip" button, and when I click on one of the other buttons, the collapsible content becomes visible. What else should happen?

Comment: @Moritz, the bug is that with the tooltip present, the collapse doesn't toggle anymore (remove the tooltip to see how the collapse should work). On a closer inspection, two toggle events seem to be sent, making the tooltip close and re-open when a button is clicked. Initially I thought the fact there are two controls for it might have something to do with it, but the bug also happens with only one controlling button.

Comment: @Vivek, at first glance, this looks like a Bootstrap bug. Consider opening an issue on their repo. Meanwhile, the only *"fix"* in sight is to switch either functionality (collapse or tooltip) to a dedicated plugin.

Comment: Thanks @tao I have created an issue in Bootstrap's GitHub repo. Hopefully, they'll look at it and address it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't instantiated Bootstrap properly. You were using:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js'; // ❌ nope
```

instead of

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import 'bootstrap'; // ✅ happy days
```

This seems to fix the error. I haven't looked into why it happens, but my wild guess is some stuff (e.g: collapse!?) gets imported/instantiated more than once.

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-pjifyf?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FHelloWorld.vue).

---

Additionally, I found two more unrelated errors (while I was looking for anything that might cause your problem):

1. `App.vue` should not have an id of `app` on the root element, because the entire app is mounted in the already existing `div#app` (from `public/index.html`), which results in the following faulty markup (`id`s should be unique):

```html
<div id="app">
  <div id="app">
    ... your app here
  </div>
</div>
```

2. You seem to be instantiating the Tooltip differently than what the docs are showing ***<sup>1</sup>***.
   In [the docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/tooltips/), the first param of the `Tooltip` constructor is always the element selector, not the tooltip container. The container selector (or element) should be passed using the `container` option.
   I'm quite surprised it works the way you're using it. I beleive the correct way to do it is:

```
new Tooltip('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]', {
  // can be skipped, `document.body` is the default value
  container: document.body,
  // other options, instead of providing them via data-bs-* attributes...
})
```

---

***<sup>1</sup>*** - Although what you're using seems to produce the desired outcome, I thought I should mention it since it's not complying with the documentation and might stop working at any point.

Comment: You're a star @tao